# Simple exchange calculator in Java - structure and tests

Tags: java, algorithm, calculator

I am trying to learn how to correctly structure my projects and write a good, clean code. I would also like to learn how to write good tests. Can you please review it and give me some tips and tricks how to make that better?

The application is calculating the exchange from the bill for lemonade. Lemonade costs 5$ and client may pay with 5$, 10$ or 20$. At the beginning there is no change available.

### Project structure

My project structure is as follows:

LemonadeChange (project) with src package and 4 packages inside:

- app (contains Main)
- calculatorImp (contains CalculatorLongImp and CalculatorShortImp)
- calculatorInterface (contains CalculatorInterface)
- test (contains CalculatorTest)

### Classes

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(int[] args) {
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorLongImp();
        calc.lemonadeChange(args);
    }
}
```

CalculatorInterface

```
public interface CalculatorInterface {

    public boolean lemonadeChange(int[] bills);
}
```

CalculatorLongImp

```
public class CalculatorLongImp implements CalculatorInterface {
    private int five = 0;
    private int ten = 0;
    int acc = 0;

    public boolean lemonadeChange(int[] bills) {
        for (int bill : bills) {
            if(bill == 5) {
                five++;
            }
            else if(bill == 10) {
                five--;
                ten++;
            }
            else {
                if(ten >= 1 && five >= 1) {
                    ten--;
                    five--;
                }
                else if (five >= 3) {
                    five -= 3;
                }
                else {
                    acc++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(acc == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

CalculatorTest

```
public class CalculatorTest {

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldBePossibleToGive() {
        int[] bills = {5,5,5,10,20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorLongImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
        calc = new CalculatorShortImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGive() {
        int[] bills = {20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorLongImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
        calc = new CalculatorShortImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGiveSecond() {
        int[] bills = {10, 20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorLongImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
        calc = new CalculatorShortImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldBePossibleToGiveSecond() {
        int[] bills = {5, 5, 10, 20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorLongImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
        calc = new CalculatorShortImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGiveThird() {
        int[] bills = {10, 20, 5, 5};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorLongImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
        calc = new CalculatorShortImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldBePossibleToGiveThird() {
        int[] bills = {5,5,5,5,20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorLongImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
        calc = new CalculatorShortImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }
}
```

How would you improve that? Any tips and tricks welcomed!

Please let me know if you want to see the task that it solves - that is one of the tasks on LeetCode, so I can post it if that makes review easier.

Comment: Yes, please include the task description in the question. Also, what is `CalculatorShortImp`?

Comment: Here you have the task itself:
https://leetcode.com/problems/lemonade-change/

The CalculatorShortImp contains the implementation of calculator that was prepared by someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Code Review! I'll dive right in:

---

#### Project Structure

Java projects **tend** to have a following structure:

```
Module
^-src
  ^-main
    ^-java
      ^-Your applications top level package
        ^-your application
    ^-resources
      ^-property files and such
  ^-test
    ^-java
      ^-Your applications test packages
        ^-your applicationtests
    ^-resources
      ^-property files for tests
```

Your applications top level package should have a reasonably unique name. The convention in most cases is to reverse the domain where it is hosted.For example, if you were writing an applet hosted at codereview.stackexchange.com, convention says your package inside the main/java directory would be something like

```
^-com
  ^-stackexchange
    ^-codereview
      ^-appName
```

---

I see you are coding to an interface! Good, this is commonly held as a best practice. However, the package structure around this type of coding is very opinion based.
You could keep each interface and implementation alone in there own directory like so:

```
appName
^-sub1
  ^-interface1
  ^-impl1
^-sub2
...
```

and some choose to make a second "impl" subdirectory:

```
^-sub1
  ^-impl
    ^-impl1
  ^-interface1
```

These are just examples of common use

---

On to actual code ~

---

#### CalculatorLongImp

**I noticed you don't track how many 20s you receive**, is this intentional?

The method lemonadeChange breaks convention: the method returns a boolean true/false based on where or not the bills passed could make a valid transaction. For readability, convention here is to make such Boolean methods a true/false question. A name more in line with convention would be isValid, or IMHO, isValidTransaction

Also, as @herdistheword commented, 'acc' isnt a very descriptive name. To write good code means to write code that others could maintain. Do you think another developer could look at that name and know what it is? if not, consider renaming it.

SPEAKING OF ACC: At the end of your method, you check if acc is 0 or not, and then return a true or false. I would recommend making acc a `boolean`, replacing `acc = 0` with `acc = true`, replacing `acc++` with `acc = false`, and then finally replacing your last `if(){}else{}` block with a simple `return acc`. Same results, less work.

---

#### Writing Tests

The bests tests are tests that have been in mind since the inception of the project. One approach to better tests is to **design your code based on the tests it needs to pass**. This way, you know upfront what you need to test, and what tests your code must pass to meet requirements.

> The application is calculating the exchange from the bill for lemonade. Lemonade costs 5$ and client may pay with 5$, 10$ or 20$. At the beginning there is no change available.

From the above, you have a guideline for what to test:

> The application is calculating the exchange from the bill for lemonade. Lemonade costs 5$

Your first test should be proof that it correctly calculates the necessary change for a test case

> Clients may pay with 5$, 10$ or 20$

That's three cases, each one should return true in a test(In some of these you will need to 'initialize' your change before your assert test)

> At the beginning there is no change available

So test use with a 10 or 20 as the first transaction should return false

That's 5 good tests just from your requirements statement, and its easy to see that code that can pass all 5 tests is at least adjacent to done

---

My last suggestion is to look at your tests. I mentioned above,

> (In some of these you will need to 'initialize' your change before your assert test)

If you keep in mind that every time you call new Calculator, you reset your 5s/10s/20s to zero, you will see that some of your tests are expecting money to be there when it is not.

Comment: Amazing explanation with some small tricks and tips for making code better :)

I have to say that I prefer keeping interfaces in a separate package, so I will keep that convention.

As I can see there are some changes that I need to do, so I will add a comment with a final version of code tomorrow.

Thank you especially for a tip how to write the tests, I was just picking some random values and wondering what result that should return. Now it will be much better structured. Better structure - better understanding as you really have to know what do you want to test, not only put random.

Comment: Happy to be of service! Please accept my answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

First off, the implementation of lemonadeChange is pretty complicated. I get worried whenever I see a bunch of nested if statements - these always lead to bugs. Indeed, try adding another test case where you only pass $10 bills, I think it will erroneously return true. It's generally a good idea to limit the complexity of any individual function, take a look at the concept of Cyclomatic Complexity: https://help.semmle.com/wiki/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=29393453#content/view/29393453

Also, if you call lemonadeChange more than once on the same instance of CalculatorLongImp then the values of five/ten/acc will persist between calls, giving you odd results. Generally, you'd say this function has "side effects", and it's often a good idea to avoid these where possible.

It's good that you've included tests. I would separate these out so each test only covers a single implementation - specific tests covering a single function on a single class make it easier to see exactly what's broken.

Finally, I find the naming a bit confusing. What does acc do? What's the difference between CalculatorLongImp and CalculatorShortImp? Imagine someone else will be reading your code tomorrow and trying to understand what it does. Naming things clearly will make it much easier for someone else (or yourself in the future!) to read and understand your code.

Comment: Hi!

Thank you a lot for your comment! 

I agree that naming can be a bit confusing as CalculatorLongImp stands for Calculator Long Implementation - the one prepared by me, which is longer than prepared by my friend (CalculatorShortImp). But that is something that only I know, so for sure should be changed.

I will try to make the code shorter by mysel - I can see how to improve code by removing acc variable now. I used that as a flag for the case when it is possible to give the change or not.

Comment: Regarding tests - that what you say is that I should create separate test classes for the two implementations that I have?

Also - is the structure of packages correct and clear? 
Should I publish the code once again here once I am done with the refactoring that you suggested?

Comment: @Marcin  Codereview tends to view the improved code as a side show. The main event is the review/feedback discussion here in the answers and comments. Thus, muddling the question with an update of new code tends to confuse other users and could attract downvotes. I would recommend publishing a 'self-answer' with the improved code, rather than an update to the question. Just keep in mind not to accept it as the answer final answer

Comment: @DapperDan, thanks! I will add the comment with the final version of the code tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT - adding explanations what was changed in the code]

Here is my final version of a code:

Project structure:

```
Module
^-src
   ^-app
      Main.java
   ^-calculatorImp
      CalculatorImp.java
   ^-calculatorInterface
      CalculatorInterface.java
   ^-test
      CalculatorTest.java
```

And the final version of the classes:

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(int[] args) {
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        calc.lemonadeChange(args);
    }}
```

**CalculatorImp**

Removed acc variable, changed the last if else statement to true or false on the basis of number of fives and tens instead of value of acc variable

```
public class CalculatorImp implements CalculatorInterface {
    private int five;
    private int ten;

    @Override
    public boolean lemonadeChange(int[] bills) {
        five = 0;
        ten = 0;

        for (int bill : bills) {
            if (bill == 5) {
                five++;
            } else if (bill == 10) {
                five--;
                ten++;
            } else {
                if (ten >= 1 && five >= 1) {
                    ten--;
                    five--;
                } else if (five >= 3) {
                    five -= 3;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if(five >= 0 && ten >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }}
```

**CalculatorTest**

Added several test cases - starting from the most basic ones, so the change for 5$, 10$ and 20$ and then the combinations of that.

```
public class CalculatorTest {

    @Test
    public void testChangeShouldBePossibleToGiveFor5$Transaction() {
        int[] bills = {5};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGiveFor10$Transaction() {
        int[] bills = {10};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGiveFor20$Transaction() {
        int[] bills = {20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testChangeShouldBePossibleToGiveForFirstTransaction5$() {
        int[] bills = {5,10,20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGiveForFirstTransaction10$() {
        int[] bills = {10,20,5};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGiveForFirstTransaction20$() {
        int[] bills = {20,5,10};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldBePossibleToGiveForMultipleTransactions() {
        int[] bills = {5,5,5,10,20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGiveForMultipleTransactions() {
        int[] bills = {20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGiveForMultipleTransactions2() {
        int[] bills = {10, 20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldBePossibleToGiveForMultipleTransactions2() {
        int[] bills = {5, 5, 10, 20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldNotBePossibleToGiveForMultipleTransactions3() {
        int[] bills = {10, 20, 5, 5};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertFalse(calc.lemonadeChange(bills)); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllChangeShouldBePossibleToGiveForMultipleTransactions3() {
        int[] bills = {5,5,5,5,20};
        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImp();
        assertTrue(calc.lemonadeChange(bills));
    }}
```

**CalculatorInterface**

```
public interface CalculatorInterface {

    public boolean lemonadeChange(int[] bills);
}
```

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity of lemonadeChange method can be reduced. 
I have just found another very clever solution on the internet (in LeetCode discussions), but as I implemented it this way I will leave the algorithm as it is.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: You must also specify what has been revised in this version.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find in Help tab, YouTube or in questions how to write the code comparison here side-by-side. Can you give me a tip how to do that so that we can close this topic?

Comment: You just need to mention what changes you've made, such as at the top of the post.  I'm not quite sure how else to explain it.